# Trouble installing spim on OS X

Tags: macos, assembly, terminal, spim

I am trying to run spim in the OS X Terminal.  I am able to use QTSpim, but the `spim` command in Terminal does not exist yet.  I'm a bit of a newbie when it comes to the Terminal (just switched from Windows) so maybe this is really obvious.

First I just navigated to the spim folder and typed `make`.

```
Lasker:spim orthogonal$ make
./Configure
cc
Check if this machine is big-endian or little-endian.
This may take a few minutes.
I believe this is a little-endian machine.
Looks like a Mac OS X / OpenStep universe exists...
Scanning libc.dylib

Checking if libc on this machine contains:
  vsprintf: No, I don't think
    _doprnt: NO, THIS IS A PROBLEM: NO VSPRINTF AND NO _DOPRNT
SPIM WILL NOT RUN PROPERLY
  vfprintf: No, I don't think
    _doprnt: NO, THIS IS A PROBLEM: NO VFPRINTF AND NO _DOPRNT
SPIM WILL NOT RUN PROPERLY
  strtoul: No, I don't think
  strtol: No, I don't think
  memcpy: No, I don't think

Checking for /usr/include/termios.h
Yes, it is there
make -f Makefile spim2
bison -d --file-prefix=y ../CPU/parser.y
../CPU/parser.y: conflicts: 25 shift/reduce
gcc -I. -I../CPU `cat configuration` -DTEXT_SIZE=65536 -DDATA_SIZE=131072 -DK_TEXT_SIZE=65536 -DDEFAULT_EXCEPTION_HANDLER="\"/usr/local/lib/spim/exceptions.s\"" -DSPIM_VERSION="\"`cat ../VERSION`\"" -g -Wall   -c -o spim-utils.o ../CPU/spim-utils.c
In file included from ../CPU/spim-utils.c:39:
../CPU/spim.h:71:1: warning: "memcpy" redefined
In file included from /usr/include/string.h:190,
                 from ../CPU/spim-utils.c:36:
/usr/include/secure/_string.h:53:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
../CPU/spim-utils.c:501: error: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant
../CPU/spim-utils.c:504: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘{’ token
../CPU/spim-utils.c:520: error: conflicting types for ‘strtol’
/usr/include/stdlib.h:181: error: previous declaration of ‘strtol’ was here
make[1]: *** [spim-utils.o] Error 1
make: *** [spim] Error 2
```

I went back and read the [installation guide](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~larus/SPIM/spim.html) again and it said to try `make install`:

```
Lasker:spim orthogonal$ make install
make -f Makefile spim2
gcc -I. -I../CPU `cat configuration` -DTEXT_SIZE=65536 -DDATA_SIZE=131072 -DK_TEXT_SIZE=65536 -DDEFAULT_EXCEPTION_HANDLER="\"/usr/local/lib/spim/exceptions.s\"" -DSPIM_VERSION="\"`cat ../VERSION`\"" -g -Wall   -c -o spim-utils.o ../CPU/spim-utils.c
In file included from ../CPU/spim-utils.c:39:
../CPU/spim.h:71:1: warning: "memcpy" redefined
In file included from /usr/include/string.h:190,
                 from ../CPU/spim-utils.c:36:
/usr/include/secure/_string.h:53:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
../CPU/spim-utils.c:501: error: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant
../CPU/spim-utils.c:504: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘{’ token
../CPU/spim-utils.c:520: error: conflicting types for ‘strtol’
/usr/include/stdlib.h:181: error: previous declaration of ‘strtol’ was here
make[1]: *** [spim-utils.o] Error 1
make: *** [spim] Error 2
```

Then I tried something else from the installation guide,

```
Lasker:spim orthogonal$ make test
make -f Makefile spim2
gcc -I. -I../CPU `cat configuration` -DTEXT_SIZE=65536 -DDATA_SIZE=131072 -DK_TEXT_SIZE=65536 -DDEFAULT_EXCEPTION_HANDLER="\"/usr/local/lib/spim/exceptions.s\"" -DSPIM_VERSION="\"`cat ../VERSION`\"" -g -Wall   -c -o spim-utils.o ../CPU/spim-utils.c
In file included from ../CPU/spim-utils.c:39:
../CPU/spim.h:71:1: warning: "memcpy" redefined
In file included from /usr/include/string.h:190,
                 from ../CPU/spim-utils.c:36:
/usr/include/secure/_string.h:53:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
../CPU/spim-utils.c:501: error: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant
../CPU/spim-utils.c:504: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘{’ token
../CPU/spim-utils.c:520: error: conflicting types for ‘strtol’
/usr/include/stdlib.h:181: error: previous declaration of ‘strtol’ was here
make[1]: *** [spim-utils.o] Error 1
make: *** [spim] Error 2
```

What's going wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: I don't know how to fix it, but are you required to use spim? If not, [MARS](http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/) is a fantastic cross-platform (Java) alternative.

Comment: Yes, I need to use spim.

Answer (score 1):

For those trying to compile on OS X with spim 8.0, I'd recommend this procedure:

```
$ tar xvf spim-8.0.tar.gz
$ cd spim-8.0/spim
$ ./Configure
$ cat > configuration
-DLITTLEENDIAN
-DUSE_TERMIOS
-U_POSIX_SOURCE
^D
$ make install
```

Comment: You should also include `-O2` in your `configuration`.  The code compile commands in the question don't include any optimization options, so the resulting SPIM will run much slower than necessary if you don't include them in the config.

Answer (score 1):

You can get `spim` through Homebrew:

```
brew install spim
```